# Check if no datarows returned

Tags: c#, linq, if-statement, datatable

I have this which check for datarows which match an expression:

```
DataRow[] foundRows = this.callsTable.Select(searchExpression);
```

How do i check if it returns some datarows, so basically if it returns none don't do what's in the if function?

I have tried:

```
if (foundRows != null) { }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `Length` property of *array* to check if you get any rows

```
if (foundRows.Length == 0)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is accessing the length property faster than calling Count()? I assume it is, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: @NWard `Count()` optimises where possible. From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx), *If the type of source implements `ICollection<T>`, that implementation is used to obtain the count of elements. Otherwise, this method determines the count.*

Comment: Length seems to be faster because it's not a method, it is a property. But in my opinion, it executes some operations during the get (not only getting some value from a variable). So, its basically the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Count method to verify:

```
if (foundRows.Count() == 0)
```

Comment: Have you checked your solution ? `foundRows` is an array, You can not use `Count` method, You need to check the lentgh of the array.

Comment: Yes, Soner is right. The method Count() is different from the property Count.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following with LINQ

```
var areThereAny = foundRows.Any();

var count = foundRows.Count();
```

If you only want to find out whether there are any rows that match your condition, you can do the following:

```
var anyThatMatch = this.callsTable.Any(selectCondition);
```

Answer (score 0):

check the length of the array like this

```
   if (foundRows.Length > 0) 
   {
        //Your code here
   }
```

or you can check with Count() too

```
   if (foundRows.Count() > 0)
   {
     //Your code here
   }
```